# How retrieve files from my SharePoint site using REST API

Tags: sharepoint

If somebody can help trying to understand how the SharePoint rest API works, because I am trying to get of my files that is in my SharePoint site but I didn´t get luck with that.

Comment: Share the code that you are using to retrieve files.

Comment: Do you want to fetch data from list/library/specific folder from your library? Please elaborate your question.